# Cannot access my wp-admin after installing Gzip compression

Tags: plugins, wp-admin, fatal-error, account, compression

I have installed a WP Plugin called Gzip Compression to increased the speedpage and had an awful surprised: have no access to the website at all, giving me an error of invalid form of compression, and the worst thing is that the website is not displayed in the Intenet for two weeks now which is going to affect badly my analytics. 
I am not a good IT guy but I am self-taught person ready to learn more.

Please, help!
Susana

Comment: Do you see any errors? Try activating `WP_DEBUG` fron `wp-config.php` and check.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to log onto your FTP server and goto the wp-content folder -> plugins -> and delete the GZIP plugin you have installed.

If you are not sure about FTP, you can probably try and go through your web server control panel, they usually have some sort of file browsing option.

You might also need to check the .htaccess file also, but just try removing the plugin first!

Cheers

Andy